# How to Add host name in grafana dash board under host?

Tags: grafana, prometheus

I'm using Promethues and Grafana for monitoring.
(Monitoring 10 servers.)

In Grafana dashboard , under **host** it was listing the IP of the servers( 10 servers) which was mentioned under **promethus.yml** file.

It is difficult to identify the server with the host name.

I need to display the corresponding host name in the **host**  or along with IP address i need to add some names to differentiate and understand it immediately.

Answer (score 1):

Now i can able to display the corresponding host name in the Grafana dashboard instead of IP.

```
Corresponding dashboard --> manage dashboard--> Templating --> variable--> Edit
```

Edited the varibale section and replace the `label_values(node_load1, instance)` with `label_values(nodename)`.

But values(data) were not loading for that host. Reports as **no data**